# unnest() used, but still cannot access field text on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<text STRING, language STRING>>, big query

Tags: struct, google-bigquery, unnest

I'm using bigquery to search for patents that contain the word 'metal' in the title. My query:
[image: My query]

Then I got the following error message:
[image: Error message]

I checked the data structure for title_localized:
[image: The title_localized array]

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.
Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use UNNEST this way to query nested fields:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT country_code
FROM
  `patents-public-data.patents.publications`,
  UNNEST(title_localized) AS t
WHERE
  t.text LIKE '%metal%'
```